# Animating position of UIButtons causes them to stop receiving touch actions

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uikit

In my app I have several buttons that, after a separate button is pressed move to new positions in a UIView animation.  The animation itself works perfectly, but the problem is, after the animation, the four buttons stop responding to touch actions.  Here's my current code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.hexagon.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
            self.tileB.center.x += self.tileB.bounds.width
            self.tileB.center.y += self.tileB.bounds.height
            self.tileF.center.x -= self.tileF.bounds.width
            self.tileF.center.y += self.tileF.bounds.height
            self.tileH.center.x -= self.tileH.bounds.width
            self.tileH.center.y -= self.tileH.bounds.height
            self.tileD.center.x += self.tileD.bounds.width
            self.tileD.center.y -= self.tileD.bounds.height
        }, completion: nil)
```

I have tried many other methods, including setting frames and bounds, but none of them have worked correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913157/iphone-uibutton-nested-in-uiview-does-not-respond-to-touch-following-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The animation itself works perfectly, but the problem is, after the animation, the four buttons stop responding to touch actions

The reason is probably that after the animation, the buttons have moved out of their superview's bounds. A view outside of its superview is untouchable, even if it is visible.

One way to confirm this is to set the superview's `clipsToBounds` to `true` and do the animation. The buttons will *vanish* by the end of the animation, proving that they have moved outside their superview.

Comment: Ok—that makes a lot of sense. I had the buttons each in individual stack views and, like you said, the animation takes them out of that view. Do you know any way to adjust the supervise to include the new frame?  If not, I’ll just scrap the StackViews and go with individual constraints, which should work fine.

Comment: You can do hit-test munging on the superview to allow a subview outside it to be tappable, but the whole idea of animating a stack view's arranged view is completely wrong so I would abandon the stack view if I were you. One more point: note that you can animate a view's _transform_, making its position _appear_ to change.

Comment: I assumed as much. Thanks a ton!  I rarely use stack views for this very reason, but I guess I felt like I should for this case. (bad move i guess) Abandoning the StackView should work for this situation.